# Time complexity for loops

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science

I am having some trouble figuring out the time complexity in big theta notation of the following algorithms. Any help is appreciated.

int j = 1;
        int n = any;

```
    while( j < n){
        int k = j;
        while(k < n) {
            if (k % 2 == 1) {
                k++;
            } else {
                k += 0.01 * n;
            }
        }
        j += 0.1 * n;
    }
```

I think it's O(1) because outer loop executes 10 times and inner loop can vary but it's or +1 or 10 times too. But after a +1 it advances n/10. And after it advances n/10 it can advances n/10 or +1.

Comment: We are interested in the behaviour as $n\to\infty$, but note that the loop will not terminate for $2\le n\le 9$ (and the case $n=10$ may depend on floating point precision). - Same argument for the inner loop if $n\le 99$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the increments `0.01 * n` and `0.1 * n` will actually evaluate to $\lfloor \frac n{100}\rfloor$ and $\lfloor \frac n{10}\rfloor$ - except that we may have rounding errors from `float` to `int` conversion; but then again we must allow unbounded values for the `int` type (or we can say the complexity is vacuously $O(1)$), so why not assume infinite precision for the `float` type?
At any rate, $\lfloor \frac n{100}\rfloor>\frac n{100}-1>\frac n{200}$ if $n>200$. Hence for such $n$ the inner loop will advance $k$ by more than $\frac n{200}$ in any two consecutive rounds (because the first `if` branch acnnot be taken twice in a row); therefore it will loop at most 200 times. Liekwise, for $n>200$ we have $\lfloor \frac n{10}\rfloor >\frac n{10}-1>\frac n{10}-\frac n{200}=\frac{19}{200}n $ and hence the outer loop will loop at most 22 times. Therefore we obtain a constant bound for the running time for all $n>200$. Complexity is therefore $O(1)$ (and vacously also $\Omega(1)$ and so $\Theta(1)$).

Note that for $2<n<100$, the inner loop may fail to terminate at all. Likewise, for $2\le n<10$ the outer loop may not terminate.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Hagen. How did you come up with the constant constraints? Is it because experience? I figured out the complexity time because my gut's feeling but I can't come up with a mathematical explanation like you. How do you do it? And, why for n < 100 the loop may be infinite if it keep moving forward even if it's in order of n/100.

Comment: @Manuel `k`is declared as `int`, hence can only advance by `int`steps. As you used a C-like syntax, I assumed C-like semantics. And there the conversion of `0.01 * 99` to an `int` produces `0`.

Comment: I get it. It's language related issue. Thank you very much @Hagen.